# `nameof` operator in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

There is `nameof` operator in C#, it allows to get property name at compile time:

```
var name = nameof(User.email);
Console.WriteLine(name);
//Prints: email
```

It is not possible to use reflection in `flutter` and I do not want to hardcode names of properties i.e. to be used for querying SQLite tables. Is there any workaround?

***Currently I'm using `built_value` library.

Comment: There is no workaround except using custom code generation (like built_value does or json_serializable, ...)

Answer (score 1):

For the archives, I guess, this isn't possible as Dart doesn't store the names of variables after compiling, and as you mentioned, Flutter doesn't support reflection.

But you can still hardcode responsibly by grouping your properties as part of the object that they belong to, like with JSON:

```dart
class User {
  final String email;
  final String name;
  const User({required this.email, required this.name});

  Map toJson() => {
    "email": email,
    "name": name,
  };
}
```

Instead of remembering to type out "email" and "name" whenever you use `User`, just call `User.toJson()`. Then, when you want to rename your variables, you can use your IDE's "rename all", or just skim over your `User` class to quickly change all of the names without missing any.

Comment: Just for the record. nameof in C# is a compile time operation, the end code contains a string. It's not reflection.

Comment: @MihaMarkic I do believe that is called "compile-time reflection" which dart (and by extension Flutter) also doesn't support.

Comment: @jari I'm not sure where you got that term. It's just a language feature implemented by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently monitoring the progress on the `dart:mirrors` package, which offers some neat reflective properties and methods, though, I hadn't found a simple way to just get the name of a symbol like `nameof()` does.

**Example:**

```
import 'dart:mirrors';

class User {
  final String email;
  final String name;
  const User({required this.email, required this.name});
}

void main() {
  reflectClass(User).declarations.forEach((key, value) {
    print(value.simpleName);
  });
}
```

**Output:**

```
Symbol("email")
Symbol("name")
Symbol("User")
```

These are of type `Symbol`.

More here: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.0/dart-mirrors/dart-mirrors-library.html

So, until they develop a nameof, I've created an extension on symbol:

```
extension SymbolExtensions on Symbol {
  String get nameof =>
      RegExp(r'"(.*?)"').firstMatch(toString())!.group(1).toString();
}
```

So, you could do:

```
print(reflectClass(User)
  .declarations[#email)]!
  .simpleName
  .nameof);
```

**Output:**

```
email
```

It's a start. Dart is still growing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code generation.

The basic idea is to create a `nameof` annotation class and mark parts of your code with it. You also need to create a code generator that handles your annotated code. Look at the `json_serializable` package for an example and create your own code generator.

If you do not want to create your own generator, use a ready-made package `nameof`: https://pub.dev/packages/nameof

#### Short how-to with this package.

1. Mark your class with `nameof` annotation.

```dart
@nameof
class Car {
  final double price;
  final double weigth;

  final int year;
  final String model;

  Car(this.price, this.weigth, this.year, this.model);

  Car.sedan(double price, double weigth, int year)
      : this(price, weigth, year, 'Sedan');
}
```

2. Run the code generator.
   `flutter pub run build_runner build`

Then use the generated class, which will look something like this.

```dart
/// Container for names of elements belonging to the [Car] class
abstract class NameofCar {
  static const String className = 'Car';

  static const String constructor = '';
  static const String constructorSedan = 'sedan';

  static const String fieldPrice = 'price';
  static const String fieldWeigth = 'weigth';
  static const String fieldYear = 'year';
  static const String fieldModel = 'model';
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can implement your own [nameOf function](https://pub.dev/documentation/servicestack/latest/servicestack/nameOf.html):

```
String? nameOf(dynamic o) {
  if (o == null) return "null";

  try {
    if (o is List) {
      var first = o.length > 0 ? o[0] : null;
      if (first != null) {
        var elementType = nameOf(first)!;
        Log.debug("nameOf: List<$elementType>");
        if (!isMinified(elementType))
          return "List<$elementType>";
      }
    } else {
      Function? getTypeName = o.getTypeName;
      if (getTypeName != null) return getTypeName();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    Log.debug("ignored nameOf error: $e, falling back to o.runtimeType: ${o.runtimeType}");
  }

  return o.runtimeType.toString();
}

bool isMinified(String type) => type.startsWith("minified:");
```

Comment: To work like C#'s `nameof` operator, this function should return the variable's or method's name (which would need compiler support), but it just gets the variable's type name.